# Custom claims handler/filter for wso2is 5.7.0

Tags: ldap, openid, claims, wso2-identity-server

I have setup a wso2 identity server 5.7.0 and configured a secondary LDAP user store for it. I also mapped the role claim to extract the role from the secondary user store and configured everything for oauth2/openId.

If I retrieve the AccessToken I get the roles returned, but they have the domain name of my LDAP user store in front of the role, e.g. ldap.my.domain/myRole. Additionally an "internal/everything" role is returned.

Is it possible to configure this that the domain prefix is removed and also the internal roles?

I also saw in the documentation that you can extend wso2is by writing osgi bundles. Following some examples in the docs and some code I have found on the net I tried to write a bundle for my problem, placing it to dropins / lib folders and updating the identity.xml but it seems that the bundle is not working because I don't see any logs from it.

Can someone point me in the direction how to debug this or to a sample project for an osgi bundle that works with wso2is 5.7.0?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to configure this that the domain prefix is removed and
>   also the internal roles?

There is a configuration to remove user store domain is under Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration of Service Provider untick 'Use user store domain in roles'
[image]

Removing "internal/everything" role is not supported.

> Can someone point me in the direction how to debug this or to a sample
>   project for an OSGi bundle that works with wso2is 5.7.0?

you can use the OSGi console mode to diagnosis why the bundle did not get activated

```
diag <bundle_id>
```

For more details refer [this](http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-debug-wso2-carbon-products-using.html)